# Changing elements in WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I've created a Web Service in Java (Using Eclipse & Axis) and I'm having some trouble doing some final changes to the way the response from the web service is displayed.

I'm deploying the web service by exporting it to a .war from Eclipse and then onto Weblogic.

This is basically the response for a request;

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getRelationshipListResponse xmlns="domain.net">
         <getRelationshipListReturn>
            <clientTransactionId>25</clientTransactionId>
            <patient>
               <demographics>
                  <dateOfBirth>1990-12-01</dateOfBirth>
                  <gender>M</gender>
                  <givenName>John</givenName>
                  <middleName/>
                  <surname>Hope</surname>
               </demographics>
               <identifier>
                  <MRN>X12345T</MRN>
                  <assigningAuthority>AAAA</assigningAuthority>
               </identifier>
            </patient>
            <relationships>

               <relationships xsi:type="ns1:Relationship" xmlns:ns1="domain.net">
                  <ns1:directDomain>h1</ns1:directDomain>
                  <ns1:displayName>Orion1</ns1:displayName>
                  <ns1:lastRelationshipDate>2013-08-15</ns1:lastRelationshipDate>
                  <ns1:relationshipCount>1</ns1:relationshipCount>
               </relationships>

               <relationships xsi:type="ns2:Relationship" xmlns:ns2="domain.net">
                  <ns2:directDomain>h2</ns2:directDomain>
                  <ns2:displayName>RLS Test</ns2:displayName>
                  <ns2:lastRelationshipDate>2013-09-13</ns2:lastRelationshipDate>
                  <ns2:relationshipCount>1</ns2:relationshipCount>

               </relationships>
            </relationships>
            <serverTransactionId>ca25e772-fbe8-4f98-83ff-d79ae16a3637</serverTransactionId>
         </getRelationshipListReturn>
      </getRelationshipListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I need to move the `<serverTransactionId>` element to the top, so it's just below `<clientTransactionId>`, Also, The items inside `<relationships>`, start with `<relationships>` instead of `<relationship>` (Since it's a single relationship item), where would I go about changing these things?

I've checked the whole java project, and there doesn't seem to be anything I can change to reflect on this, I've changed changing the .wsdl file generated inside the .war, but it doesn't have any effect!

Comment: Unfortunately thats the problem with developing web services code-first instead of contract-first. The WSDL that is generated is in response to the Java classes you have written, and sometimes they are not interpreted exactly as you want. Ideally you create a WSDL by hand (using the Eclipse WSDL designer) and then use a tool such as `wsdl2java` or `wsimport` (depending on which JAX-WS stack you use) to generate the Java classes from it. The WSDL would define exactly the XML structures the way you want them.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html

Comment: @jbx In the .war file is a .wsdl (in the wsdl folder), I'm editing this and then re-deploying the war, however the WSDL which is displaying seems to be different from this. Does this mean that Weblogic is generating the WSDL from my java code instead of the .wsdl is that folder?

Comment: I've confirmed it doesn't use the wsdl in the wsdl folder by removing it and then deploying it. Seems it's just there for show!

Comment: Yes unfortunately thats how JAX-WS works. The default behaviour is that it exposes the WSDL by generating it on the fly from the Java Objects. If you are restricted to a specific WSDL (for instance if someone provided the WSDL for you) you can simply generate the classes from the WSDL and then fix a little where it breaks in your Java code, since some names or structures might change a little. Otherwise fix the WSDL you found and change it to your liking (clean it up a little because its likely to have rubbish) and generate your Java classes from your new version.